# Code for reversing a string word by word is given below. Put a condition in while loop so that following program starts working completely

Tags: c

Code for reversing a string word by word is as follow -

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    char str[]="you are selected";
    char *q,*r,*s;
    q=str;
    while(*q!=NULL)
    {
        q++;
    }
    q--;
    s=q;
    while(q!=str) //i tried for q!=str-1 but its not working
    {
        if(*q==' ')
        {
            r=q+1;
            while(r!=s+1)
            {
            printf("%c",*r);
            r++;
            }
            printf(" ",*r);
            s=q-1;
        }
        q--;
    }
}
```

but the problem is that above code is not printing first word since in condition part of the while loop i am checking address of the start of string not equal to address hold by q. Since for the first word condition becomes false. please modify the condition so that it gives desired output.

Comment: Do you want a C solution or a C++ solution?

Comment: do u want the output as "uoy era detceles" ?

Comment: @chris
i wants solution in c.

Comment: @vishwa.deepak
No, i wants output as, "selected are you".
one more example, if input is- "one two three four" then output should be "four three two one"

Comment: `" ".join("you are selected".split()[::-1])` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Modify the while loop to be a do.. while loop

@ashrafi iqbal

```
do
{
    if(*q==' ')
    {
        r=q+1;
        while(r!=s+1)
        {
        printf("%c",*r);
        r++;
        }
        printf(" ",*r);
        s=q-1;
    }
    q--;
}while(q!=str);
```

___*EDIT****_*_**

modify if condition as

```
if ((*q==' ') || (*q == str[strlen(str) - 1))
```

Comment: Please check the code. if i remove q-- then it will not traverse whole string.

Comment: @ashrafiiqbal just modify while loop to be a do..while

Comment: wont (*q==' ') eval to false on the first word because *q = 'y'? if so, then the first word will be missed.

Comment: still its not printing the word "you". i wants output as "selected are you"

Comment: Please don't modify the whole while loop just modify condition inside while loop (if possible) to get desired output ie for string "you are selected" output should be "selected you are" another example is for string "one two three four" output should be "four three two one"

Comment: while going through ur code again I found that, initially q points to end of string, which is 'd' in this case. And hence it will fail to satisfy the condition q == ' '.

Comment: modify if condition as if ((*q==' ') || (*q == str[strlen(str) - 1))

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while(1)
{
  if(q==str)
  {
    //Logic to print first word
    break;
  }
  if(*q==' ')
    {
        r=q+1;
        while(r!=s+1)
        {
        printf("%c",*r);
        r++;
        }
        printf(" ",*r);
        s=q-1;
    }
    q--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines after the for loop. This will take care of the word not preceded by a space (i.e. the first word)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    char str[]="you are selected";
    char *q,*r,*s;
    q=str;
    while(*q!=NULL)
    {
        q++;
    }
    q--;
    s=q;
    while(q!=str) //i tried for q!=str-1 but its not working
    {
        if(*q==' ')
        {
            r=q+1;
            while(r!=s+1)
            {
            printf("%c",*r);
            r++;
            }
            printf(" ",*r);
            s=q-1;
        }
        q--;
    }
    r = q;
    while (*r != ' ' && *r != NULL)
    {
       printf("%c", *r);
       r++;
    }
}
```

Comment: please check the code, i am not using q to traverse string from start to end. I am using it to traverse from end to start. Please compile the program once then you will get it.

Comment: I ran the code with the changes and it works.. Replace `q` with `r` and add the line `r=q` before the added while loop.

Comment: @ashrafiiqbal can't you just do what Umair Azmi says? ***please post your code here. then i'll check*** doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: @OscarMederos earlier he posted a code which was not working. Thats why i wrote....

Comment: **Replace `q` with `r` and add the line `r=q` before the added while loop**... that's what he said. Can't you just change that by yourself, and test it?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `while` loop to:

```
while(1)
{
    if(*q==' ' || q == str)
    {
        if(q == str)
            r = q;
        else
            r=q+1;

        while(r!=s+1)
        {
            printf("%c",*r);
            r++;
        }
        printf(" ",*r);

        if(q == str)
            break;

        s=q-1;
    }
    q--;
}
```

Also,

- `str-1` is asking for a segfault.
- Checking if `*q` is NULL is bad style. Use `strlen` instead.

Comment: actually when this ques asked to me a catch was there you can't use string liberary so i did that...